# Disable GC in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection, v8

Is there a way to disable GC completely (or) scavenger, atleast? Find the discussion here - https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/462 and here - https://twitter.com/dolftax/status/825742173698142209

I've tried `node --nouse_idle_notification --trace_gc --max-old-space-size=1000 --max-semi-space-size=64 --noconcurrent_sweeping example.js`

Still both Scavenge and Mark-Sweep doesn't stop. Refer the Github issue for more info.

My question is, am I missing something? Is there anything else I could do to let GC not run. FYI, This is for an experimental purposes and do not want alternative solutions without stopping GC.

Node v7.9.0

V8 5.4.500.45

Answer (score 2):

I managed to bend the GC run as required.

`node --max-old-space-size=1000 --max-semi-space-size=512 --noconcurrent_sweeping example.js`

.. did wait for the max old space size to reach 1000 MB before running Mark Sweep.